# how to parse dynamic _POST variable in php

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

I'm stuck with a php/mySQL thing..

I have a dynamically created form and I want to parse the $_POST variables it generates. To be specific,I have a query in SQL which generates the fields in my form. Then, I need to process these variables in the php file, where the action of the form goes.

However, I cannot parse the dynamically created $_POST variables. Below is my code:

```
$sql="just-a-query";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    ${''.$data['parameterName']}=$_POST[$data['parameterName']];
}
```

For example, if I have 3 variables that got through the form the values:

```
house=1
tree=3
car=2
```

I would like to save them via php like this:

```
$house=$_POST['house'];
$tree=$_POST['tree'];
$car=$_POST['car'];
```

However I can't get through it. It returns Undefined index error. Any thoughts?

Comment: Care to post the HTML as well?

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` give you? Also I would use `$$data['parameterName']` instead of that other approach, but it shouldn't make a big difference.. just more readable

Comment: It is usually easier to loop over `$_POST` and find the keys you want to act on. `foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { // if $key is one you need....}`

Comment: so do a `var_dump($_POST)` to see what you're getting back from your form, and/or a `view source` in your browser to see what the fields' names really are.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find if a variable is defined before using it, it's as simple as using `isset()`:

```
if( isset($_POST[$data['parameterName']]) ) {
    ${''.$data['parameterName']}=$_POST[$data['parameterName']];
}
```

If on the other hand, it's supposed to be defined (you see the form element), but then it's not getting defined in the postback.  First check to make sure that your form submission type is post, then check to make sure you are using the name attribute in the form elements.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your time. My problem was that I was parsing wrong parameters from the HTML.

Yes, I'm an idiot and yes, var_dump() helped me to figure my error.

Thanks again!

btw, my code was working perfectly. Ha!